# Interfaces and Comparable

Tags: java, object, interface, abstract-class

i'm beginner and just learning abstract classes and interfaces but really struggeling to get it right.

**MY Class structure.**

- **Abstract Class** Vehicle
- **Class** Car (extends Vehicle, implements ITuning)
- **Class** Motorcycle (extending Vehicle)
- **Interface** ITuning

I want to have an abstract method **doRace()** that I can use in my Car class to compare the Car Objects (car.getHp()) and prints the winner. I try to implement a doRace(object o) into the Interface ITuning and a doRace(Car o) into my Car class but get the error. How can I implement that correctly ?

> The type Car must implement the inherited abstract method
> ITuning.doRace(Object)

But if do chage it to Object, i can't use it in my Car class…

```
public interface ITuning
{
abstract void doRace(Object o1);
}
```

```
public Car extends Vehicle implements ITuning
{
 public void doRace(Car o1){
 if(this.getHp() > o1.getHp())
 };
}
```

Any Idea what i'm doing wrong? I assume its a comprehension error

Comment: Hint: `doRace(Object o1)` and `doRace(Car o1)`. Why are you using `Object` in your interface?

Comment: Where is `getHp()` defined? In `Car` or in `Vehicle`? The basic idea would be to use that class in your `doRace()` method in the interface declaration.

Comment: Tbh I tried "Object" as a placeholder in doRace(Obeject) as I wasn't sure what to use. Whatever i tried, it does not work. 

get(Hp) is an abstract method in Vehicle Class and implemented in Car & Motorcylce class, as I wanted to use it in both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your `ITuning` interface to

```
public interface ITuning
{
    void doRace(Vehicle other);
}
```

Since `Vehicle` defines the `getHp()` method this ensures that your actual implementation can access it.

The difference to [Chaosfire's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74390214/4616087) is that this will allow you to do a race between different types of vehicles, e.g. a `Car` and a `Motorcycle`, while the generic `ITuning<T>` class will be limited to races between equal types*.

Chaosfire's point regarding the interface name is still valid.

*This is a bit over-simplified to make my point clearer. Of course `Car` could implement `ITuning<Car>` *and* `ITuning<Motorcycle>` but this may not be what you want.

Comment: Thanks Marvin, that is exactly what i was tying to do.

However  If I change this as you said where do I implement the actual method? 
If I do in the abstract Vehicles class, i don't need the Interface ITuning anymore…

Comment: Okay i think i found my Issue. My main class was following `public static void main(String[]args){.  Car car1 = new Car("bmw", 90)  Motorcycle moto1 = new Motorcyle("Ducati", 100)  Vehicle moto2 = new Motorcycle("Yamaha", 96) } ` Thats why it wasn't working. Now i changed the last Object to Motorcylce moto = new Motorcycle("Yamaha", 96) and implemented the method doRace into Motorcylce.java and Car.java. Now I can race all kinds. Thank you

Comment: I'd argue that you probably indeed do not need the `ITuning` interface. If you are unsure about the differences between an interface and an abstract class, maybe a look at [Interface vs Abstract Class (general OO)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/761194/4616087) helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can make `ITuning` generic.

```
public interface ITuning<T> {
  
  void doRace(T other);
}
```

Implementation will be like this:

```
public class Car extends Vehicle implements ITuning<Car> {

  @Override
  public void doRace(Car other) {
    //do comparison
  }
}
```

Implementation in other classes will be quite similar, just change the generic parameter.

As a side note, i would rename the interface to something more fitting. Considering that tuning a vehicle is the act of modifying it to optimise its' performance, `ITuning` providing functionality to do the actual racing is counter intuitive.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Just for clarification does that mean if i want my "interface" to interact with multiple Objects (like comparing) I need to change it to generic  ?

Comment: @EddiOne That depends. If you mean like `Comparator` and `Comparable`, which compare objects of the **same** type, yes, it has to be generic. If you want to race, let's say car vs motorcycle, **different** types, then generic is not necessary, although it can be done with generic as well, by providing bound to it. See [Marvin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74390783/17795888) for non generic solution.